# gui.Window.open() returns undefined

Tags: google-chrome, node-webkit

I have a NW application that starts with a splash screen, which then opens the main application in a new window. The code is approximately this:

```
var appWin = gui.Window.open("https://localhost:8080/", {
    "icon": "app_icon.png",
    "frame": true,
    "width": 1200,
    "height": 800,
    "position": "center",
    "resizable": true,
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200
 })

 appWin.on('loaded', function() {
    // hide the splash screen
 })
```

However, `appWin` is always `undefined`, even though the new window opens and displays the correct content.

I'm using `nw-builder` version 0.13.4, but I have also tried various versions of 0.14.x, 0.15.x and 0.16.x, with the same problem.

Any suggestions of viable workarounds would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Open a new window.
nw.Window.open("https://localhost:8080/", {
    "icon": "app_icon.png",
    "frame": true,
    "width": 1200,
    "height": 800,
    "position": "center",
    "resizable": true,
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200
 }, function(win) {
       console.log('window opened'. win);
       win.on('loaded', function() {
            console.log('window created');
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see this usage in any documentation.